# fetch records from four different table using join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table : Post

```
id       user_id     group_id    Text
1         1            1         AAA
2         2            2         BBB
3         2            2         CCC
4         3            2         DDD
5         2            3         EEE
```

Table : UserMaster

```
user_id     username   
1           Raj 
2           Meet
3           Kishan
```

Table : Groups

```
group_id     groupname
1            JAVA
2            PHP
3            SEO
```

Table : JoinRequest

```
id      user_id     group_id    status
1        1           3          deactive
2        2           2          active
3        2           1          active
4        1           3          active
```

My Query Here:

```
//Help me improve my query to get the desired result.
select  * FROM Post  
where status = active in JoinRequest table
```

and user_id='2'

Expected Result :

```
id     username       Groupname     Text     
1      Raj             JAVA         AAA
2      Meet            PHP          BBB
3      Meet            PHP          CCC
4      Kishan          PHP          DDD
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/) . Please show us what you have tried, and where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.id, u.username, g.groupname, p.text
from posts p
join userMaster u on u.user_id = p.user_id
join groups g on g.group_id = p.group_id
join joinRequest r on r.user_id = p.user_id 
                  and r.group_id = p.group_id
where r.status = 'active'
```

Comment: @sudhAnsu63: Please don't change the code style of other people to the one you prefer. I like the code in my answers the way I style it. Who says your code style is better than mine? Only change something if it is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select p.id, um.username, g.Groupname, p.Text
From Post as p
JOIN UserMaster as um
  ON p.user_id = um.user_id
JOIN Groups as g
  ON p.group_id = g.group_id
JOIN JoinRequest as jr
  ON p.user_id = jr.user_id
  AND p.group_id = jr.group_id
WHERE jr.status = 'active'
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: I don't get it, my answer is practically identical to the answer which has since been submitted and accepted yet this answer apparently isn't acceptable?

Answer (score -1):

You can get your result like this.

```
SELECT P.id,
       U.username,
       G.Groupname,
       P.Text
FROM   Post P
       INNER JOIN UserMaster U
               ON U.user_id = P.user_id
       INNER JOIN Groups G
               ON G.group_id = P.group_id
       INNER JOIN JoinRequest JR
               ON P.user_id = JR.user_id
                  AND P.group_id = JR.group_id
WHERE  JR.status LIKE 'active';
```